# How to pass parameters as part of -file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, quoting, start-process

If I run this line in a PowerShell window, it executes perfectly

```
.\buildTestAndPublish.ps1 -buildPath 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0' -testPath 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow'
```

Now I need to automate this and I'm failing to do so

```
$pth = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0'
$testPth = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow' 
start-process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList "-file $PSScriptRoot\AutomationScripts\buildTestAndPublish.ps1 -buildPath $pth -testPath $testPth"
```

> A positional parameter could not be found that accepts argument Files

This looks like it's complaining about the white space, but after a search, I've wrapped them in single quote marks AND pass them as variables (the advice I found online)

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use *embedded double-quoting*** around the arguments that may contain spaces; inside `"..."`, **escape embedded `"` as `` `" ``**, because `` ` ``, the *backtick* character<sup>[1]</sup>
, is PowerShell's escape character:

```
"-file $PSScriptRoot\buildTestAndPublish.ps1 -buildPath `"$pth`" -testPath `"$testPth`""
```

<sup>Note: `*.ps1` path shortened for readability.</sup>

**Note**: Embedded ***single*-quoting (`'...'`) does *not* work in this case**, because using the PowerShell CLI with **`-File` doesn't recognize single quotes as string delimiters**; by contrast, they are recognized as such with `-Command`.<sup>[2]</sup>

---

Note that you could **alternatively pass the arguments *invidually*, as an *array*** to `-ArgumentList`.
However, due to [a known bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576) **you must *still* apply embedded double-quoting**:

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList '-file',
  $PSScriptRoot\AutomationScripts\buildTestAndPublish.ps1,
  '-buildPath',
  "`"$pth`"",
  '-testPath',
  "`"$testPth`""
```

---

<sup>[1] Formally known as [GRAVE ACCENT, Unicode code point `U+0060`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/60/index.htm).</sup>

<sup>[2] As such, you could have used `-Command` instead of `-File`, which would then enable the following solution:

`"-Command $PSScriptRoot\buildTestAndPublish.ps1 -buildPath '$pth' -testPath '$testPth'"`, but (a) `'` is a legal character in filenames (whereas `"` is not) and the presence of `'` in a filename would break the command; and (b) `-Command` treats the arguments as PowerShell code, which can lead to additional unwanted interpretation (by contrast, `-File` treats its arguments as *literals*).</sup>

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions: I assume you're referring to `\`` which PowerShell calls the _backtick_, and it doesn't function as a string delimiter, but as a general-purpose _escape character_. Please see my update; I've also added an explanation of why single-quoting (`'...'`) doesn't work in your case.

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions: And, yes, `\`` is the grave accent character (Unicode codepoint `U+0060`)